# Maximum time for rising in a breadmaker

Tags: equipment, bread, rising

I have a Panasonic SD253 breadmaker. The function chart shows 2hr 55min - 4hr 10min rising times available for the French Bake program.  How do I make sure it rises for the full 4hr 10 mins?

Comment: And amazingly enough, having checked the manual, the manual doesn't say. Or at least I couldn't find it in the manual.

Comment: How automatic is the breadmaker? If it can detect when the dough has doubled in size, this might be why you can't set a more precise time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek of the dough every 1/2 hour.

If you see in a certain peek it's lower than the last time you saw it, it has fully risen and is starting to fall.

The dough should be about to reach it's rising limit before it begins to be baked, but not pass it. You can change the dough's rising speed changing the amount of yeast from your recipe, or controlling the dough's temperature, among other ways.

Answer (score -1):

Its down to the volume of yeast you use.

Yeast will continue to rise the bread as long as there is food and the temperature maintains within its required range (45c 115f)

so if you have 1 hour yeast and use 1/4 of the required amount for 1 hour bread, then it will take 4 hours to rise.

http://www.abreadaday.com/?p=1195

see the link above for an example of bread cooked using the no knead 4 hour rise method.

Comment: Of course this is generally true for bread, but I don't see how it is connected to changing the breadmaker setting.

Comment: There is no way to set this particular machine to a more specific time than the "window" it gives, which is between 2 hours 55 minutes and 4 hours 10 minutes.

The way to "make sure the bread rises for the full 4 hours 10 minutes" is by modifying the ingredients to allow for this.